Downsizing the Captured Image is getting rotated in .Net 8 Android
I have been working on a Migration of Xamarin.Android to .Net 8 Android.
The Image captured using MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() and Downsized. But the image is getting rotated on Display.
Can someone help me with why the rotation is happening. Am I missing something?
 var capturePic= await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
 if (capturePic!= null)
 {
     using var stream = await capturePic.OpenReadAsync();
     var image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
     IImage imagenew = image.Downsize(200);
     var resizedStream = imagenew.AsStream();
     if(resizedStream!=null)
     {
         imageBytes= resizedStream.AsBytes();
         var imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
         Platform.CurrentActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => ImagePreview.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap));
     }
    
}

Thanks in Advance!

Is your project a Xamarin project or a Maui project ?
